# C# Websocket-Sharp - how to identify clients

Tags: c#, websocket, websocket-sharp

I use websocket-sharp ( https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp ) (serveur side only).

I can have many clients applications connected to my websocket server. Each client send an ID (let's call it `CLIENT_ID`).

I want to know which websocket session is related to `CLIENT_ID`.

`IWebSocketSession` expose `ID` (let's call it `SESSION_ID`).

**What I have tried:**

Firstly I have a storage class which store for each `SESSION_ID` his `CLIENT_ID` (a simple dictionary).

When I receive a message from a client application, i store `SESSION_ID` and `CLIENT_ID` in my dictionary.

So when i want to send a message to all sessions having `CLIENT_ID == XXX` i can use this dictionary. This works fine ...

**BUT sessions are only temporary**. A client can use multiple sessions. So for a single client, I will soon have many inputs in my dictionary. When i send a message to all sessions in my dictionnary having `CLIENT_ID == XXX`, I will send the same message to the same client multiple time.

**My question is :** How to register unique clients with websocket-sharp ? Which property should I use ?

**Edit :** Even with a unique client, every 20s it changes ID of the session. It's probably a new session created for ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as I find nothing, I kept `SESSION_ID` but when i register a new item in my dictionary (`SESSION_ID` => `CLIENT_ID`) I have to manually delete all "old sessions".

This can be done by checking if `session.State == WebSocketState.Open`.

It's not perfect but it works.